# How to call a DAO method through a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, database, jsp

I'm writing a jquery code and calling a JavaScript function through it on a jsp page.

This is the jquery function

```
$(function () {

    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: $.countdown('//SomeTime'),onExpiry: liftOff});

});
```

liftOff is a javascript method which is called after the specified time expires.

This is the JavaScript function

```
<script>
function liftOff() {

    alert("Before Delete");
    &lt;% DAO_Object.deleteRecord(ID);%&gt;
    alert("After Delete");

}

</script>
```

Now here the problem is, the line `<% DAO_Object.deleteRecord(ID);%>` is getting executed before the function call and the record from database is getting deleted. The alert statements are executing correctly AFTER the function call.

Am i calling the `deleteRecord` method incorrectly?

Comment: You're conflating client side code and server side code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549/1366624

Comment: @lxe OP is trying to run JSP code dependent on browser events. It's more akin to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280767/how-do-i-run-php-code-when-a-user-clicks-on-a-link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing your server-side JSP logic with your client-side JavaScript logic.

Everything between `<% %>` runs on your servlet when it's processing the request, so the record is already deleted by the time you get the response in the browser. If you look at the HTML/JS you are receiving in the browser using [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) or similar tool, you will see that there is nothing between those `alert(...)` calls.

Your solution here is to [setup a route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446368/spring-mvc-delete-record-from-jsp-table) that handles the `deleteRecord()` on the server-side, and call it [via AJAX](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/) in your `liftOff()` method. So `liftOff()` would look something like this:

```
// assuming `id` is a string here
function liftOff(id) {

  alert("Before Delete");

  // You'll have to setup this endpoint to run 
  // your `DAO_Object.deleteRecord(ID);` code 
  // in your JSP code.

  $.get("/delete/my/record/" + id, {
    error: function(e){
      // some kind of error occurred in making the request
    },
    success: function(resp){
      // `resp` is the response from the server
      alert("After Delete");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: So what should be the solution to call the DAO method after the function is called???

Comment: @NikhilPatil HTTP request `DELETE /path/to/resource/{id}`.

Comment: @chrylis thanks. I've tried to expound on how you would actually go about making this happen. Hope that helps.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to replace the path hack with the proper HTTP verb.